# Angular error: no provider for ActivatedRoute

Tags: angular, angular-activatedroute

i m using angular 5 latest and i am hitting below exception

```
ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AppComponent -> ActivatedRoute]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AppComponent -> ActivatedRoute]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ActivatedRoute!
    at _NullInjector.get (core.js:1002)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1300)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1242)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1110)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1300)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1242)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1110)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10854)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:12087)
    at resolveDep (core.js:12577)
```

the app.module.ts looks like below
import { Routes, RouterModule }  from '@angular/router';

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    OptyDetailsComponent,
    GlobalNavbarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatInputModule
    RouterModule
  ],
  entryComponents: [
  ], 
  providers: [
    DataStoreService,
    DataObjectsOscService,
    AdobeSignService,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: How does your router configuration has written? Can you add some code?

Answer (score 54):

For being able to provide `ActivatedRoute` into your angular elements, you need to import the result of calling `RouterModule.forRoot` into your root module (AppModule). This is because the module returned by `RouterModule.forRoot` includes the provider for instances of `ActivatedRoute`, among others.

So basically you need to add the following to your imports in the root module:

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    ...
    // Remark: because you havent defined any routes, I have to pass an empty
    // route collection to forRoot, as the first parameter is mandatory.
    RouterModule.forRoot([]),
    ...
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

But to be honest, its kinda odd that you use `ActivatedRoute`, despite the fact that you haven't defined any routes for your root module.

For further details see:

[ActivatedRoute provider source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.2.6/packages/router/src/router_module.ts#L60)

[RouterModule.forRoot() source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.2.6/packages/router/src/router_module.ts#L146)

Comment: I am already using RouterModule.forRoot like so     `RouterModule.forRoot(routes,
      { enableTracing: false, onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'})`. How do i add activatedRoute to this list?

Comment: To which list? what do you mean?

Comment: according to you i should add `RouterModule.forRoot([])` to make it work. But i'm already using RouterModule.forRoot in another way. So what do i need to change in my own RouterModule.forRoot implementation so that activatedRoute is included to the `routes, { enableTracing: false, onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'}` argument list?

Comment: Added a small clarification to my answer. You dont need to do any changs to your code.

Comment: In doing so, if there is a route resolver, the initial (root)-route will never be triggered. Any suggestions for this purpose?

Comment: @dmorlock you better create a new question

Comment: I tried to set (useHash: true) and works as expected, but my url will look like: http://localhost:4200/#/product/14 and I don;t want "/#" char into my URL