# How to get query params in angular 6/7 without routes

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an angular app with a single page for a confirmation that accepts a hash value in the query. There are no routes in the application. Just a single page and the component. How can I retrieve the hash value from the url query parameter?

I tried adding ActivatedRoute to the component but got an error saying there was no provider.

I would like to avoid having to add routes for this purpose, if possible.

I ended up using https://stackoverflow.com/a/31057221/10609045

Comment: if you're talking about the hash - `window.document.location.hash`. if you're talking about the query params - `window.document.location.search`

Comment: Sorry, the hash value I meant was to retrieve the value of confirmid from something like http://example.com/confirm.html?confirmid=xYndm8ls1dkt

Comment: please provide some code on how to tried to add ActivatedRoute. It should be a dependency injection in constructor.

Comment: The code is exactly like the one in conpile's answer.

Comment: @workvact can u share your code? without code it's hard to identify what's wrong in your code

Comment: I ended up using Stavm's suggestion to use window.document.location.search and parse it.

Answer (score 1):

do i get it right, that you want to use ActivatedRoute in a component like this?:

```
@Component({..})
export class YourComponent {
   constructor(
           private readonly route: ActivatedRoute,
   ) {
      route.queryParams.subscribe( (params) => this.anyAction(params));
   }
}
```

have you added the RouterModule to the module where you declared your component?:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        YourComponent
    ]
})
export class YourModule {}
```

Comment: Yes, I added this. The error I get now is: "NullInjectorError: No provider for ActivatedRoute!"

Answer (score 0):

Check the answer at [Angular error: no provider for ActivatedRoute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49039457/angular-error-no-provider-for-activatedroute?rq=1)

You need to import `RouterModule.forRoot([])` in your `AppModule` to be able to use `ActivatedRoute`

Comment: I have no routes defined and trying to use ActivatedRoute seems odd according to that answer. I just parsed window.document.location.search.

Comment: Good thought. No need to complicate things, just follow the KISS principle.